# ReCaptha Implementation For Swift

Tags: swift, recaptcha

I try to implement Google ReCaptcha for login page of my IOS application for along time, I am researching all the sites but I can not understand how to start. I can not find a detailed example. I know a lot of titles in stackoverflow but I can not understand anyone. Please can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase Authentication has a section for reCAPTCHA verification.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#set-up-recaptcha-verification